# iBeacons proximity is unreliable

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

A while ago I bought three beacons for a project I am working on. I want to know to which beacon I am the closest and an approximate distance (e.g from 0 meters to around 2 meters).

I have the following code using Core Location: (stripped down)

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"beacons %@", beacons);
}
```

which seems to work, I get my beacons in the log. Sorted by distance. But even when I only have one beacon near. (e.g around 50 cm from my device) the proximity changes from immediate, to near and far. It just "jumps around".

Is there any way to do this more precise? In my code I now have a check where I check if the distance changed at least one time before "confirming" the change. But even then the proximity is buggy.

Comment: what brand and model of beacon are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That's surprising that it jumps around like that. Are you holding the device at the time or is it sitting still on a table? In theory, the radio signal shouldn't become substantially stronger or weaker for no reason. Perhaps there's something in your environment that's interfering.

`CLBeacon*` exposes a property, `NSInteger rssi`. This is the [received signal strength indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSSI) of the beacon. You can monitor this on a timer to see the raw signal strength in real time, however you'll then have to write your own algorithm to determine a correlation between RSSI and proximity.

It may be an interesting exercise, though, to see how interacting with the device or the environment increases or decreases signal strength.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some immediate/near jitter, but not immediate/near/far as you describe. That sounds like you might have a bad beacon. (or loose connection on the Bluetooth antenna on your iDevice... 
Or maybe Apple has broken the iBeacon API in a recent release.)

What kind of device are you using, and what version of iOS, on what kind of iDevice

Comment: I have an iPhone 5S with the newest version of iOS (7.1.1) and I have three [BLEep beacons](http://www.getbleep.com).